# SSH connection reset on windows

Tags: windows, openssh

I'm struggling to setup the OpenSSH on my Windows system.

I tried to follow both a system installation (like [this](https://medium.com/geekculture/setup-ssh-server-on-windows-10-11-34c7f096eaff)) and a manual installation from the binaries. I copied the OpenSSH files in C:\Program Files and I installed from there.

The OpenSSH server and agent seems configured properly, but when I try to ssh to the localhost I get always the following error:

```
Connection reset by ::1 port 22
```

Hereafter some debug commands:

```
Get-Service ssh-agent

  Status   Name               DisplayName
  ------   ----               -----------
  Running  ssh-agent          OpenSSH Authentication Agent

Get-Service sshd

  Status   Name               DisplayName
  ------   ----               -----------
  Running  sshd               OpenSSH SSH Server

netstat -nao | find /i '":22"'
  TCP    0.0.0.0:22             0.0.0.0:0              LISTENING       5680
  TCP    [::]:22                [::]:0                 LISTENING       5680

Get-NetFirewallRule -Name *OpenSSH-Server* |select Name, DisplayName, Description, Enabled

  Name                  DisplayName           Description Enabled
  ----                  -----------           ----------- -------
  OpenSSH-Server-In-TCP OpenSSH Server (sshd)             True

whoami

  pcname\m.ceradini

ssh pcname\m.ceradini@localhost

  Connection reset by ::1 port 22
```

The sshd_config is the default. As suggested in other tutorial I tried also to comment the Match Group Administrators in the sshd_config, but the problem persists.

Do you have any idea of what is going on? And how I could try to fix this error of connection?

Thank you very much.

---

### UPDATE:

I post here the answers to some of the questions and replies. Ssh to my own user is still not working.

For summarizing I did the following things:

- Uninstalled OpenSSH
- Deleted all the .ssh and Open-SSH related folders
- Installed again OpenSSH Client and Server (using the windows GUI - from settings) - and reboot
- Checked that all the SSH related commands and services works (Get-Command ssh,Get-Command sshd, Get-Command ssh-agent, Get-Service sshd, Get-Service ssh-agent)
- Create a new key for the user
- Added the public key to the authorized_keys in .ssh folder
- Commented the 'Match Group administrators' (as stated [here](https://medium.com/geekculture/setup-ssh-server-on-windows-10-11-34c7f096eaff)) in sshd_config
- Enabled 'PubkeyAuthentication' in sshd_config
- Checked that sshd service are running.

### debug

```
Get-Service sshd

Status   Name               DisplayName
------   ----               -----------
Running  sshd               OpenSSH SSH Server
```

> As sshd in default configuration will not serve the loopback device,
> localhost as remote usually will not work, if you didn't start a
> tunnel at that port previously:
>
> Please execute the following command:
>
> ssh pcname

```
whoami
pcname\m.ceradini

ssh -v pcname\m.ceradini
OpenSSH_for_Windows_8.6p1, LibreSSL 3.4.3
debug1: Authenticator provider $SSH_SK_PROVIDER did not resolve; disabling
ssh: Could not resolve hostname pcname\\m.ceradini: No such host is known.
```

> If the host is not found use the local IP address but not the
> 127.0.0.1 respectively not ::1

```
ssh -v 192.168.83.185
debug1: kex: algorithm: curve25519-sha256
debug1: kex: host key algorithm: ssh-ed25519
debug1: kex: server->client cipher: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com MAC: <implicit> compression: none
debug1: kex: client->server cipher: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com MAC: <implicit> compression: none
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_KEX_ECDH_REPLY
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEX_ECDH_REPLY received
debug1: Server host key: ssh-ed25519 SHA256:v7C8pJ1ci+e/ZJKhgyIvZfENRyQHd0sUJSXv8PXIEDM
debug1: load_hostkeys: fopen C:\\Users\\m.ceradini/.ssh/known_hosts2: No such file or directory
debug1: load_hostkeys: fopen __PROGRAMDATA__\\ssh/ssh_known_hosts: No such file or directory
debug1: load_hostkeys: fopen __PROGRAMDATA__\\ssh/ssh_known_hosts2: No such file or directory
debug1: Host '192.168.83.185' is known and matches the ED25519 host key.
debug1: Found key in C:\\Users\\m.ceradini/.ssh/known_hosts:1
debug1: rekey out after 134217728 blocks
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS sent
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS received
debug1: rekey in after 134217728 blocks
debug1: Will attempt key: sssapisa\\m.ceradini@TNE-Matteo ED25519 SHA256:ugTj7Iu5c0ZbiXgF6yMPO8Hru3rLp5ynP+Aku15WKX0 agent
debug1: Will attempt key: C:\\Users\\m.ceradini/.ssh/id_rsa RSA SHA256:WgcHzwF1tPBwnvdmy9KriQjn+qLuDbOhR80Bmpw10O0
debug1: Will attempt key: C:\\Users\\m.ceradini/.ssh/id_dsa
debug1: Will attempt key: C:\\Users\\m.ceradini/.ssh/id_ecdsa
debug1: Will attempt key: C:\\Users\\m.ceradini/.ssh/id_ecdsa_sk
debug1: Will attempt key: C:\\Users\\m.ceradini/.ssh/id_ed25519
debug1: Will attempt key: C:\\Users\\m.ceradini/.ssh/id_ed25519_sk
debug1: Will attempt key: C:\\Users\\m.ceradini/.ssh/id_xmss
debug1: SSH2_MSG_EXT_INFO received
debug1: kex_input_ext_info: server-sig-algs=<ssh-ed25519,sk-ssh-ed25519@openssh.com,ssh-rsa,rsa-sha2-256,rsa-sha2-512,ssh-dss,ecdsa-sha2-nistp256,ecdsa-sha2-nistp384,ecdsa-sha2-nistp521,sk-ecdsa-sha2-nistp256@openssh.com,webauthn-sk-ecdsa-sha2-nistp256@openssh.com>
debug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_ACCEPT received
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey,password,keyboard-interactive
debug1: Next authentication method: publickey
debug1: Offering public key: sssapisa\\m.ceradini@TNE-Matteo ED25519 SHA256:ugTj7Iu5c0ZbiXgF6yMPO8Hru3rLp5ynP+Aku15WKX0 agent
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey,password,keyboard-interactive
debug1: Offering public key: C:\\Users\\m.ceradini/.ssh/id_rsa RSA SHA256:WgcHzwF1tPBwnvdmy9KriQjn+qLuDbOhR80Bmpw10O0
debug1: Server accepts key: C:\\Users\\m.ceradini/.ssh/id_rsa RSA SHA256:WgcHzwF1tPBwnvdmy9KriQjn+qLuDbOhR80Bmpw10O0
debug1: Authentication succeeded (publickey).
Authenticated to 192.168.83.185 ([192.168.83.185]:22).
debug1: channel 0: new [client-session]
debug1: Requesting no-more-sessions@openssh.com
debug1: Entering interactive session.
debug1: pledge: filesystem full
debug1: ENABLE_VIRTUAL_TERMINAL_INPUT is supported. Reading the VTSequence from console
debug1: ENABLE_VIRTUAL_TERMINAL_PROCESSING is supported. Console supports the ansi parsing
client_loop: send disconnect: Connection reset
```

> Usually you should not need to use the username, as ssh will default
> to your current user. So excluding it eliminates a source of error. —
> I suspect you must not use pcname\m.ceradini but only m.ceradini as
> username. — But I'm not a primary windows user and currently can't
> verify this.

Regarding the username I tried all the possible combinations, but the outcome is always the same.

Comment: Run OpenSSH Server in verbose mode by running “sshd -d” and post the relevant **bind** information indicating by editing your question be sure to use appropriate formatting the output. This error can also be caused improper permissions on the users key files, so provide the ACL, for your key file (if you have attempted to configure it)

Comment: not sure if you ever got this resolved but something i've noticed when attempting to setup an ssh server on winddows 7 box today, when attempt to connect to its self with `localhost` or `127.0.0.1` i get the same error message as you, but when i use my lan ip address ie. `192.168.1.42` i get prompted for a password, but still can't login in using my windows password just yet.

Comment: Updated answer.

Answer (score 0):

Did you check the Firewall settings?

```
c:\Windows\system32\Firewall.cpl
```

Look at the permitted apps in the used (required) network types for a first hint.

Then you continue and check in detail:

Have a look at the *"Advanced settings > incoming rules"* and check that there is a rule that allows TCP traffic for the the "local port" 22 to the OpenSSH Server.

Update:

> I also tried with the firewall completely deactivated for being sure that it is not a firewall-related problem

Thank you for this information. Unfortunately these "Mr. Nice Guy"-answers of Windows

```
Get-NetFirewallRule -Name *OpenSSH-Server* |select Name, DisplayName, Description, Enabled

  Name                  DisplayName           Description Enabled
  ----                  -----------           ----------- -------
  OpenSSH-Server-In-TCP OpenSSH Server (sshd)             True
```

are not really helpful when it comes to debugging, instead of filling powerpoints.

*Next step:*
As sshd in default configuration will not serve the loopback device, `localhost` as remote usually will not work, if you didn't start a tunnel at that port previously:

Please execute the following command:

```sh
ssh pcname
```

where pcname should be the real hostname of your pc, but not substituted by `localhost`.

If the host is not found use the local IP address but not the `127.0.0.1` respectively not `::1`

```sh
ssh 192.168.0.5
```

Usually you should not need to use the username, as ssh will default to your current user. So excluding it eliminates a source of error. — I suspect you must *not* use `pcname\m.ceradini` but only `m.ceradini` as username. — But I'm not a primary windows user and currently can't verify this.

If this fails, please use the verbose mode and *provide the extended ouptut:*

```sh
ssh -v pcname
```

Comment: Yes. As stated in the question I added the incoming rule to the firewall for opening the 22 port. I also tried with the firewall completely deactivated for being sure that it is not a firewall-related problem

Comment: Updated answer.

Comment: “I suspect you must not use pcname\m.ceradini but only m.ceradini as username.” - While unnecessary it’s not inaccurate and thus the syntax is correct.

Comment: @Ramhound For native Windows this surely should be true, but `OpensSSH-Server` is not a native Windows development, so there might be some hooks and eyes that should be tested when problems appear.

Comment: @dodrg - I am telling you. The syntax absolutely is correct. I literally verified it myself. Furthermore, OpenSSH is OpenSSH, specifying the machine name is valid syntax. I suspect I know what the problem is but only after the author confirms my suspicions